# Which exception should I throw when a URI isn't valid?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

I am currently writing some configuration classes. One of them has a property of type URI.

Within the setter, I am using `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString()` to validate the Uri. In case validation fails I'd like to raise an appropriate exception.

Which one would you suggest? Basically I am an advocacy of exceptions which have self-explaining names, like, in this case something like "UriMalformedException", but I am also an advocacy of not cluttering up namespaces with trivial types.

Answer (score 2):

Probably https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.UriFormatException(v=VS.110).aspx

```
UriFormatException Class
```

OR

Create your own exception and throw that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'll follow your proposal, rmn36, although it is not PCL compatible. Throwing an exception and catching another one (`UriFormatException` vs. `FormatException`) kind of has a "smell" to me, but still...

Thank you anyway.

Carsten